# How to add two different strings into two variables using getline() in C++?

Tags: c++, string, file-handling

I want to add a word and it's meaning from a file using getline() function into two different string variables word and meaning.
The text file is as follows :

```
Car an automobile with four wheels
Bike an automobile with two wheels
```

I want to store "Car" as the word and "an automobile with four wheels" as the meaning and so on for each line. Can it be done using getline() function? Is there another simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using only `getline` function, but there is a little bit more elegant solution using both `genline` and `operator >>`.

**Note:** it is work for c++11. It could be rewritten for earlier c++. Look at [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline) for reference.

### **Only `getline` using**

Here is a program which prints a file with words and its meaning.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_dict(std::string const& file_path) {
  std::ifstream in(file_path);
  std::string word, meaning;
  while (std::getline(in, word, ' ')) { // reads until space character
    std::getline(in, meaning);          // reads until newline character
    std::cout << word << " " << meaning << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string file_path = "data.txt";
  print_dict(file_path);
}
```

### **Another way**

Because `operator >>` reads one token from a stream, the `print_dict` function could be rewritten in following way:

```
void print_dict(std::string const& file_path) {
  std::ifstream in(file_path);
  std::string word, meaning;
  while (in >> word) {         // reads one token
    std::getline(in, meaning); // reads until newline character
    std::cout << word << " " << meaning << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works. Sorry if my question wasn't specific, I'm new here.